# Caracter desconocido en la salida de System.out.print();

Tags: java

```
System.out.print("¿Deseas agregar otro articulo a tu pedido? [S/N]: ");

respuesta =teclado.nextLine();
respuesta = respuesta.toUpperCase();
```

Al digitar este código en la pantalla al inicio me sale una A? alguien sabe como arreglar que no salga, o es normal?

[image]

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu IDE? Conviene que configures la salida a UTF-8 desde el mismo para evitar este problema.

Comment: ¿Usas maven o alguna herramienta para gestionar las dependencias?